# How to read distance from Elasticsearch response

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch.net

I am using *Elasticsearch V6*, *NEST V6*.

I am searching ES as below and I am using ScriptFields to calculate the distance and include it the result.

```
var searchResponse = _elasticClient.Search<MyDocument>(new SearchRequest<MyDocument>
{
    Query = new BoolQuery
    {
        Must = new QueryContainer[] { matchQuery },
        Filter = new QueryContainer[] { filterQuery },
    },
    Source = new SourceFilter
    {
        Includes = resultFields    // fields to be included in the result
    },
    ScriptFields = new ScriptField
    {
        Script = new InlineScript("doc['geoLocation'].planeDistance(params.lat, params.lng) * 0.001")   // divide by 1000 to convert to km
        {
            Lang = "painless",
            Params = new FluentDictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "lat", _center.Latitude },
                { "lng", _center.Longitude }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Now, I am trying to read the search result and I am not sure how to read the distance from the response, this is what I have tried:

```
// this is how I read the Document, all OK here
var docs = searchResponse.Documents.ToList<MyDocument>();

// this is my attempt to read the distance from the result
var hits = searchResponse.Hits;
foreach (var h in hits)
{
    var d = h.Fields["distance"];
    // d is of type Nest.LazyDocument 
    // I am not sure how to get the distance value from object of type LazyDocument
}
```

While debugging I can see the distance value, I am just not sure how to read the value?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/returned-fields.html)

To read search document and distance:

```
foreach (var hit in searchResponse.Hits)
{
    MyDocument doc = hit.Source;    
    double distance = hit.Fields.Value<double>("distance");  
}
```

And if you are only interested in distance:

```
foreach (var fieldValues in searchResponse.Fields)
{
    var distance = fieldValues.Value<double>("distance");
}
```

Comment: Updating the docs for Stored fields to point to the doc you've linked.

Comment: Now live: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/script-fields-usage.html